# Web application doesn't get actual data from database, using EclipseLink

Tags: java, jsf, websocket, jax-rs, eclipselink

I've got a database with table User

```
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   id (pk)             |   name                      |      role              |
-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   1                   |   Adam                      |           1            |
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
|   2                   |   Jack                      |           2            |
```

I got all users, using EclipseLink from database and display them in web application, using JSF and Facelets. I can edit them, add new User, everything works fine.

Backend:

```
public void getAvialableUsers() {
    List<DctInternalUsers> activeInternalUsersList = new ArrayList<>();
    activeInternalUsersList = crossInterfaceJSFBean.getSettingsBean().getAllUsers();
}
```

Frontend:

```
 <p:dataTable id="usersDataTable"
                                 emptyMessage="Пользователи отсутсвуют"
                                 selectionMode="single"
                                 value="#{usersJSFBean.avialableInternalUsersList}"
                                 var="user"
                                 rows="15"
                                 paginator="true"
                                 paginatorAlwaysVisible="false"
                                 paginatorPosition="bottom"
                                 rowKey="#{user.login}"
                                 selection="#{usersJSFBean.selectedInternalUser}"
                                 style="text-align: center;"
                                 class="commonGrid">

                        <p:column headerText="Login">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{user.login}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Name">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{user.name}"/>
                        </p:column>

                        <p:column headerText="Role">
                            <p:outputLabel value="#{user.role}"/>
                        </p:column>


   </p:dataTable>
```

And also I can add them with JAX-RS services with JSON; When I do this, I send message to my frontend using WebSockets that new user was added.

```
@Path("/addUser")
@POST
@Consumes("application/json; charset=UTF-8")
public String getUserInfo(String json) {
    try {
        JSONObject json = new JSONObject(json);

        User user = new User();
        user.setName(json.getString("name"));
        user.setRole(json.getInt("role"));

        entityManager.merge(user);

        for(Session session : sessions) {
        RemoteEndpoint.Basic endpoint = session.getBasicRemote();
        try {
            endpoint.sendText(message);
        }
        catch(IOException ioe) {
            LOG.warn("Unable to send message to session\n Message:" + 
            ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

Here everything works fine, data successfully added to database. After that, when I recive message from websockets, I go to database and try to get all users again:

```
public void updateUsers() {
    activeInternalUsersList = crossInterfaceJSFBean.getSettingsBean().getAllUsers();
}
```

And here's the problem. I recive only users, which I get in first select. New added users don't upload to Web application. The question is how to get new users from database when they was added from webservices?
Query:

```
@NamedQuery(name = "Users.findAll", query = "SELECT d FROM Users d")

public List<Users> getAllUsers() {
    TypedQuery query = em.createNamedQuery("Users.findAll", Users.class);
    return query.getResultList();
}
```

Summary: User can be added from web application and web service via eclipselink. WS send message to web application via WebSockets. On message trying to load users from database but receiving only old users. New users appear only after application restart

Comment: Are you in a transaction?  Changes are only synchronized to the database during flush or commit of an associated transaction, and only visible to other threads after the commit.

Comment: Looks like a cache problem.  Try `@Cache(isolation=CacheIsolationType.ISOLATED)` and see [EclipseLink Cache Architecture](http://www.eclipse.org/eclipselink/documentation/2.5/concepts/cache001.htm)

Comment: I’m using EJB, it controls transactions. I need to do flush to synchronize them?

Comment: Check your database that your 'merge' is actually inserting entities in your table, as you can't read what wasn't inserted. EJB does not control transactions, you still must demarcate when you want them and nothing you've shown implies this is happening within a transaction. Em.flush will throw an exception clearly indicating you are missing something if it isn't done within a transaction.

Comment: `@Cache(isolation=CacheIsolationType.ISOLATED)` worked, thanks!

Comment: Odd since findAll type queries like this always use the database, not the shared cache.  Glad it works, but I suspect something else is going on, like you were caching query results too.